# How to use arrayUnion in Firestore correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a new javascript object to an array field in a Firestore collection using the Node.js Firebase Admin SDK.

I am certain that the doc that I am targeting has the field in question but I keep getting the error: TypeError:

`Cannot read property 'arrayUnion' of undefined`

I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230367/firestore-arrayunion) but the fix does not help.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Route in question:

```
router.post("/create-new-user-group", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { userId, usersName, groupName } = req.body;

    if (!userId || !usersName || !groupName) return res.status(422).send();

    const groupRef = await db.collection("groups").doc();

    const group = await groupRef.set({
      id: groupRef.id,
      name: groupName,
      userId,
      members: [{ id: userId, name: usersName, isAdmin: true }],
    });
    
    const response = await db
    .collection("users")
    .doc(userId)
    .update({
      groups: fbApp.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
        id: userId,
        name: userName,
      }),
    });


    res.send(group);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error creating new group:", error);
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
});
```

firebaseInit.js:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("../serviceAccount.json");

const firebaseApp = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://xxx-xxxxx.firebaseio.com",
});

exports.fbApp = firebaseApp;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is telling you that `fbApp.firestore.FieldValue` is undefined.  So, it doesn't have any properties or methods for you to call.

If you want to use `FieldValue`, you will have to refer to it via the `firebase-admin` namespace import, not through an initialized app instance.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const FieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue;

// now you can write FieldValue.arrayUnion(...)
```